# Django Rest Framework serialize additional fields from intermediate model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am developing a small application that lists the customers of a store. I'm trying to retrieve the additional fields of the intermediate model because a contact can belong to several stores but depending on the store it is premium or not and if he is happy or not.

Here's the JSON response I'd like to get for a Store like **/contacts/?store=my_store**

```
[
    {
        "id": "UX",
        "first_name": "UX",
        "last_name": "UX",
        "email": null,
        "mobile": null,
        "happy": True,
        "premium": True
    },
    {
        "id": "AX",
        "first_name": "AX",
        "last_name": "AX",
        "email": null,
        "mobile": null,
        "happy": False,
        "premium": True
    }
]
```

here are my models:

```
class Store(BaseModel):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Contact(BaseModel):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    stores = models.ManyToManyField(
        Store, through="MemberShip", through_fields=("contact", "store")
    )


class MemberShip(BaseModel):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(
        Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="contact_to_store"
    )
    store = models.ForeignKey(
        Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="store_to_contact"
    )
    happy = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and my serializers:

```
class MemberShipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MemberShip
        fields = ("contact", "store", "happy", "premium")


class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ("id", "name")


class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    infos = MemberShipSerializer(
        source="contact_to_store" many=True, read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = (
            "id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "mobile", "infos"
        )
```

As you can see, I first tried to gather all the information of the intermediate model in a field before displaying **happy** and **premium** but, strangely enough, the **infos** field is returned with an empty array value.
Python v 3.7
Django v 2.1
DRF v 3.9

Answer (score 1):

You must provide data to `MemberShipSerializer` . You can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). Like that:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    infos = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = (
        "id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "mobile", "infos"
        )

    def get_infos(self,obj:Contact):
        return MemberShipSerializer(obj.contact_to_store.all(),many=True).data
```

Comment: Doesn't work the field **infos** is still an empty list
`"infos": []`

Comment: Could you check whether any MemberShip records related with contact object is exist in your db?

Comment: It works the problem is that it returns ALL the stores to which the contact is affiliated while I'm trying to display only the additional fields of the store that is passed in parameter like **contact/?store=my-store**

Answer (score 0):

I tried kamilyrb's solution here's what I changed:

```
class MemberShipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MemberShip
        fields = ("contact", "store", "happy", "premium")


class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ("id", "name")


class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    happy = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    premium = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = (
            "id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "mobile", "happy", "premium"
        )

    def get_premium(self, obj):
        return MemberShipSerializer(obj.contact_to_store.all(), many=True).data

    def get_happy(self, obj):
        return MemberShipSerializer(obj.contact_to_store.all(), many=True).data
```

This is what i have now:

```
[
    {
        "id": "UX",
        "first_name": "UX",
        "last_name": "UX",
        "email": "0",
        "mobile": null,
        "happy": [
            {
                "store": "my-store",
                "contact": "UX",
                "happy": true,
                "premium": false,
            },
            {
                "store": "my-store2",
                "contact": "UX",
                "happy": false,
                "premium": false,
            }
        ],
        "premium": [
            {
                "store": "my-store",
                "contact": "UX",
                "optin_sms": true,
                "happy": false,
                "premium": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

how can i get that ?

```
[
    {
        "id": "UX",
        "first_name": "UX",
        "last_name": "UX",
        "email": null,
        "mobile": null,
        "happy": True,
        "premium": True
    },
    {
        "id": "AX",
        "first_name": "AX",
        "last_name": "AX",
        "email": null,
        "mobile": null,
        "happy": False,
        "premium": True
    }
]
```

I also noticed that all the stores to which a contact is affiliated are shown but as I said before the url is called as follows contact/?store=my-store